# Move files from/to ftp server

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

A client needs to move files to/from a ftp server on a scheduled basis, but I do not have any experience with this.

Does anyone know of a server/client solution that permits this?

The client and server will both have folders named IMPORT and EXPORT, where the client MOVES (copy/delete?) files from EXPORT on server to IMPORT locally and equally from EXPORT locally to IMPORT on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up trying out something called ScriptFTP, which seemed to provide what I needed.